# Query Optimization, Case and Concatenation

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am new to sql and I need to optimize a query which takes about 15 minutes to run on hadoop. My boss told me to get start with the "case"

```
SELECT 
CONCAT (ZSYTMM_AE1.NUMNF, 'A', ZSYTMM_AE1.SERIE) AS receipt,
CONCAT (ZSYTMM_AE1.NUMNF, 'A', ZSYTMM_AE1.SERIE) AS external_receipt,
zsytsd_pa_plant.plant as plant,
ZSYTMM_AE1.LIFNR as suppliercode, 

(CASE
    WHEN SUBSTRING ( ZSYTMM_AE1.LIFNR, 1 , 2 ) = 10 THEN 'VI'
    WHEN SUBSTRING ( ZSYTMM_AE1.LIFNR, 1 , 2 ) = 11 THEN 'VI'
    WHEN SUBSTRING ( ZSYTMM_AE1.LIFNR, 1 , 2 ) = 12 THEN 'VI'
    WHEN SUBSTRING ( ZSYTMM_AE1.LIFNR, 1 , 2 ) = 13 THEN 'MI'
    WHEN SUBSTRING ( ZSYTMM_AE1.LIFNR, 1 , 2 ) = 14 THEN 'MI'
END) as reference_type

FROM dl_edge_base_sapprdmerc_11324_base_prd_sapr3.ZSYTMM_AE1 ZSYTMM_AE1

inner join dl_edge_base_sapprdmerc_11324_base_prd_sapr3.zsytsd_pa_plant zsytsd_pa_plant
ON  zsytmm_ae1.werks = zsytsd_pa_plant.plant
```

Any ideas how to improve the case, or the concatenation?

[image: Output]
Thx

Comment: this code makes not query slow, you should take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/query-optimization and edit your question

Comment: Please update your question to show the complete SQL statement and the output you get from running EXPLAIN PLAN for that query

Comment: It won't make it faster, but you can shorten your CASE to four lines instead of seven: `CASE WHEN SUBSTRING( ZSYTMM_AE1.LIFNR, 1 , 2 ) IN (10,11,12) THEN 'VI' CASE WHEN SUBSTRING( ZSYTMM_AE1.LIFNR, 1 , 2 ) IN (13, 14) THEN 'MI' END;`

Comment: I've updated the query and the output

Comment: Are there other possible values for `SUBSTRING ( ZSYTMM_AE1.LIFNR, 1 , 2 )` other than 10-14 ? and are you interested in those other records?

Comment: well, it could always be blank or null, but there should not be other numerical values)